# Android Download File by AsyncTask doesn't work with 3G just with Wi-Fi

Tags: android, file, download, android-asynctask

I've searched a lot about that, but no answers found.

I want to download a file (giving url, destination and file name).
I've a class that extends AsyncTast class.
It works well with Wi-Fi connection, but it doesn't work with mobile data (G, 3g, H)!
I can't figure out why, I'm going crazy.

Can anyone ever had my same or similar problem? Thanks!

I post my code below.
Thank you

```
public class AsyncDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
     try {
         Log.v("Downloader", "Source: " + sUrl[0]);
         Log.v("Downloader", "Destin: " +sUrl[1]+"/" + sUrl[2]);
         URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
         URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
         connection.connect();
         // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
         int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

         // download the file
         InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
         OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(sUrl[1]+"/" + sUrl[2]);

         byte data[] = new byte[1024];
         long total = 0;
         int count;
         while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
             total += count;
             // publishing the progress....
            // publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
             output.write(data, 0, count);
         }

         output.flush();
         output.close();
         input.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
     return null;
 }
}
```

From the Main Activity..

```
AsyncDownloader downloader = new AsyncDownloader();
downloader.execute("http://....", "...destination...", "...filename...");
```

In the destination directory SOMETIMES I found the file but it's not completelly downloaded or it's 0 kB..

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I use this function for check connection (It seems to works well):

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
       cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

LogCat (very long - complete): http://pastebin.com/EL4DREwB
LogCat (short, essential - start-finish app runtime): http://pastebin.com/wPYDQH3P

Comment: When you say 'it doesn't work with mobile data' do you have stack traces or can you describe what isn't working?

Comment: Do you check to see if the user is connected to the internet before calling the asynctask?

Comment: I've improved my question, I've attached the complete logcat

Comment: If I print the "total" progress when I use 3G the value is NEGATIVE!!! When I use Wi-Fi it grow, from 1 to 100. WHY?!

Comment: I was hunting the bug and I discovered that using mobile connection (3g), the program arrive at line:29 of the AsyncDownloader.class (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());) and doesn't continue! It's look like is loading or waiting..

Comment: Are you calling at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

please check your code  network connectivity code. you may checking only for WIFI connectivity , that why you AsyncTask not execute, you may use this

```
      public  static boolean getNetworkStatus(){
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo !=null && netInfo.isConnected();
}
```